# How do I copy an error line from logfile to another file using python?

Tags: python

I'm developing a script that should scan a night run log file.

This script should print the whole lines that the word: "error" is shown there,  into another log file named Analyzer which will  going to create during the script running.

The output is an empty new log file, without  the willing lines, the code is developed on python and I linked it to here:

```
import time
import datetime
import logging
import subprocess
import shlex
import sys

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename='Analyzer_for_NR_log_'+str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[0]+'.log', filemode='a',
format=str(datetime.datetime.now())+' %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

with open('NR_2021-12-20.log', 'r') as NightRun_Log:
    LookingForError = 'ERROR'
    for num, line in enumerate(NightRun_Log, 1):
        if LookingForError in line:
            logging.info('Error at line:', num, line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
            logging.info('Error at line:', num, line)
```

Additionally, there's a bunch of imports there you didn't need:

```
import datetime
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO, filename='Analyzer_for_NR_log_'+str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[0]+'.log',
    filemode='a', format=str(datetime.datetime.now())+' %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

with open('file.txt', 'r') as NightRun_Log:
    LookingForError = 'ERROR'
    for num, line in enumerate(NightRun_Log, 1):
        if LookingForError in line:
            logging.info(f'Error at line: {num} {line.strip()}')
```

Note that I added a `.strip()` to the `line`, to get rid of an extra newline.

Also note that you have `format=str(datetime.datetime.now())+ [etc.]` which works, but is maybe not what you want - it'll date all lines with the exact same date and time, while you perhaps want `format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'` instead, if you want to log when the other line was found.

Finally, note that you're only looking for `'ERROR'`, so you'd be missing `'error'`; also, you're naming variables like `LookingForError`, but in Python `looking_for_error` is preferred to avoid confusion with classes (i.e. no capitalisation for variables or functions).

Comment: Thank you so much, it runs perfect now. 
B.T.W, I want to add function that will print the string: Night run failed if there is at least 1 error that found. 
how can I do that out of my function in a way that this alert will be printed once and not each time an error is found?

Comment: There's many way to achieve that, but a very simple one would be to set a boolean to `False` before the for loop, and once you reach the `logging.info()` call, check if the boolean is still `False`, if so print the message and set the boolean to `True`. Alternatively, you can just set the boolean to `True` and check it after the loop completes (which is a bit faster, but prints the message at the end instead of as soon as it's found)